# How can I get only one value from Angular FromGroup as an object?

Tags: angular, formgroups

I am trying to get a value from angular formgroup. But, it returns as a value. How do I get it as an object with the property name and value. For example: I have a FormGroup with firstname, lastname and email.
I am trying to get the value of only lastname using formcontrol as below. No matter how I try it still gives me the value if I am targeting one property.

```js
let x = new FormGroup({
option1:new formControl[false],
option2: new formControl[false],
option3:new formControl['']
});

//If I log the formgroup on click it gives me the following output
console.log(this.x.getRawValue())
//Output
{option1: false, option2: false, option3: ""}

//If I log just one control value
console.log(this.x.get('option2').value)
//Output
false

//My Expected Output
{option2: false}
```

**Note:**
I know how to get the value from the control. I am looking on how to get it as a object with property. Sorry, there might be some syntax error in the above code. But, I hope I explained it clearly.

Below is the my code if needed. In this I am trying to get the input value as an object with its property:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fzzunv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Would `console.log({option2: this.x.get('option2').value})` work?

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic exactly?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz @Donald Duck What if I don't know the value name as option2? I understand I can do it with using some variable approach. But, is there any other way or a method to grab the value from the form something simple like ```this.form.getRawValue('option2')```

Comment: There isn't, and you would still have to know the name for that. Is your form created dynamically from some JSON data for example?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz - No, I guess I have to go with the suggested approach. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you wrote, I'm not too sure but it looks like it could be:

```
console.log({ option2: this.x.get('option2').value })
```

Or do you expect something else maybe?

Comment: I guess I have to go with this if there is no alternate way. I am not sure why angular doesn't have a way to get the Property and Value together.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand why you'd need that. It's the same api as a Map for example. If you have a Map called myMap when you do `myMap.get('someKey')` it does only return the value. So I can see why angular is not doing that but the workaround is simple enough that if it works for you, fine